# How do you use Vuforia on VisionOS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, visionos

How do you use Vuforia on VisionOS?

This is not officially supported, but since Vuforia is supported on Hololens and people have gotten MRTK to work - I wonder if someone has also somehow figured out a hack here?

Comment: afaik MRTK is more c# based and ships as managed c# scripts and plugins. Also MRTK is specifically ambitious on supporting all types of XR platforms, not only HoloLens in specific - Vuforia afaik just ships as precompiled DLLs for specific platforms they support ... if VisionOS is not one of them then there is probably little you can do about it.

Comment: This feels more like a vuforia feature request. For those please use the issue only repo here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine

Answer (score 0):

Vision OS currently is not a supported platform by Vuforia Engine. As far as I know it is not possible to access any of the Vision Pro cameras. This would be needed by Vuforia image-based trackers.